# adding custom tracer in wso2am 4.0.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

i want to add APM as a custom open tracer in wso2am version 4.0.0 but i can't find anything about custom tracing in the documentation. in the previous version of wso2am i.e 3.2.0 there was a section which explained how to  [add custom tracer](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/monitoring/monitoring-with-opentracing/#use-custom-tracer-implementation). it sounds like that section has been removed in the latest version. any idea how can i add elastic APM as custom tracer?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the same section in here for APIM 4.0.0.
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/api-manager/traces/monitoring-with-opentracing/#using-the-custom-tracer-implementation